# Textarea scrollbar: cannot read previous message

Tags: javascript, html

I also tried separately. This did not work:

```
$(setInterval(function(){
    $('#tr').load('halka.php');
    $('#tr').scrollTop($('#tr').scrollTop() - $('#tr')[0].height());
},1000));
```

Thank you very much fixed the problem.

Comment: did you try putting a `-` (negative) sign in front of `$('#tr')[0].height()` ?

Comment: Or even saying `$('#tr').scrollTop($('#tr').scrollTop() - $('#tr')[0].height());`

Comment: yes tried , does not seem to work ... then it just stops refreshing ...

Comment: Well I mean, you're putting the entire interval into a jQuery object.  What does your console say when you launch the page?

Comment: oopss I am using notepad++ as a beginner no idea about console ....
but in browser it refreshes the page with new message in the textarea 
and the scroll bar goes bottom making the most recent message available ...

Comment: Failed to load resource http://toolbar.utorrent.com/css/ut_foundation.css
5
Traced function is unsupported in Chrome ConduitAbstractionLayerFront.js:3949
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating all.js:56
Failed to load resource http://toolbar.utorrent.com/css/images/toolbar/toolbar_logo.png
GET http://toolbar.utorrent.com/css/images/toolbar/action_sprite.png  

console out...

Comment: The rest won't fit in a comment.  Edit your original post and place it in a code block at the bottom.